# What is the common solution for changing the C# Dto class properties' first letter to

Tags: javascript, c#

I have Dto classes in the backend where the property names starts with capital letters in accordance with C# style, like below. As a result the property names in javascript side also starts with capital letters which is not - let's say - javascript standard.

Before I start to do some magic which iterates through the property names and changes them I would like to know is there any industry standard to change the property names in this way?

I already understand that Breeze has a configuration option for this, but I do not use Breeze at the moment. I haven't checked how they are doing.

```cs
public class ModuleDto
    {
        public virtual string ModuleName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual string ModuleDesc
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

```html
<accordion>
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="item in vm.leftHandMenu">
            <accordion-heading>
                {{item.ModuleName}}<i class="pull-right glyphicon"></i>
            </accordion-heading>
            <div ng-if="item.ModuleScreenDtos !== 'undefined'">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="screenItem in item.ModuleScreenDtos">{{screenItem.ModuleScreenName}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
```

Expected result:

```html
<accordion>
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="item in vm.leftHandMenu">
            <accordion-heading>
                {{item.moduleName}}<i class="pull-right glyphicon"></i>
            </accordion-heading>
            <div ng-if="item.moduleScreenDtos !== 'undefined'">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="screenItem in item.moduleScreenDtos">{{screenItem.moduleScreenName}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your DTO model's properties with `JsonProperty(Name="...")`([link](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm)) annotation and serialize it with [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

More info: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: Just a little extension for your answer. It seems the Name property is not needed.

Comment: @SayusiAndo Probably, but I still prefer to have it so it's perfectly clear what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using an angular-js and c# by the code syntax.

- As it is correct as a standard to have the first letter of public
  properties capitalized.
- As angular model-binds to the c# classes automatically...I would say that it is correct for it to be capital first letter in angular as its a one to one mapping.
- An added bonus of this is that you will easily be able to tell the
  originator of the property(c# property DTO (public)).
- You now have to debate whether you want to change the c# standard to
  support your JS requirement, me I would leave it the way it is... as its
  predictable and makes sense.

I think ultimately this comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right it is kind of style. However, I see that it is commonly used and I would like to follow the main style.